# React Redirect when clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, routes

I´m learning in react and practicing making a simple application to login and view messages sent.
   I´ve read a lot about routing, links and redirect, but i couldn´t translate to my app.
  I Would like to click in the "Login" button of a component and redirect to another component.

Here i have the principal component : App.js

```html
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    loggedIn:false
  };


  loginHandle = () => {
    this.setState({loggedIn:true});
  }

  render(){
    return (
            <div className="container d-flex h-100">
                <div className="row align-self-center w-100">
                  <div className="col-6 mx-auto"> 
                    <div className="jumbotron">
                    <form name="form1">
                      <fieldset>
                        <legend>Chat App</legend>
                          <label for="UserName" className="col-form-label">Username</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control col-12" id="UserName"></input>
                          <label for="Password" className="col-form-label">Password</label>
                          <input type="text" className="form-control col-12" id="Password"></input>
                          <button type="button" value="log in" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.loginHandle}>Login</button>
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <div style={{float:"right"}}>
                      <div className="login-help ">
                        <a href="#" className="badge badge-light">Register</a> - <a href="#" className="badge badge-light">Forgot Password</a>
                     </div>  
                   </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
    );
  }
}
  
  
export default Login;
```

I wrapped all the Links in a Navigation component
So, when i route /, it goes to the Login component

```html
  class Login extends Component {
   state = {
     loggedIn:false
   };


  loginHandle = () => {
   this.setState({loggedIn:true});
  }

  render(){
   return (
    <div className="container d-flex h-100">
     <div className="row align-self-center w-100">
       <div className="col-6 mx-auto"> 
      <div className="jumbotron">
      <form name="form1">
        <fieldset>
       <legend>Chat App</legend>
         <label for="UserName" className="col-form-label">Username</label>
         <input type="text" className="form-control col-12" id="UserName"></input>
         <label for="Password" className="col-form-label">Password</label>
         <input type="text" className="form-control col-12" id="Password"></input>
         <button type="button" value="log in" className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={this.loginHandle}>Login</button>
                      </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <div style={{float:"right"}}>
                      <div className="login-help ">
                        <a href="#" className="badge badge-light">Register</a> - <a href="#" className="badge badge-light">Forgot Password</a>
                     </div>  
                   </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default Login;
```

Do i have to import routes and redirect in the Login component, or i have to mange all from the App component?
Sorry about this mess, but i don´t know how to continue

Thanks a lot. I really apreciatted in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for navigating to another route.

For example you can wrap your `Forgot password` like following:

`<Link to="/forgotRoute">Forgot password?</Link>`

Don't forget to add `/forgotRoute` handling into your Navigator config (where you routed `/` to your `Login` component).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for what you want i think it is. So follow me..

You need to use router. In my case i'm using react-router-dom.

First router App component, by default page its renders DefaultPage components and in DefaultPage when component mounted you can render client anywhere.

index.js looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


class DefaultPage extends Component {
    state = {
        autorized: false,
        mounted: false,
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        const { autorized } = this.state;
        if (!autorized) {
            this.props.history.push('/login');
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            mounted: true,
        });
    }

    render = () => {
        if (!this.state.mounted) {
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                  <p>Waiting...</p>
              </React.Fragment>
            )
        }

        return (
          <React.Fragment>
              <p>Hello...</p>
          </React.Fragment>
        )
      }
}

class Login extends React.Component {
    handleLogin = () => {
        if (contidion) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }

    render = () {
      return (
        <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Click to login</button>
      )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render = () {
      return (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={DefaultPage} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route component={DefaultPage} />
        </Switch>
      )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter >
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me: this.props.history.push('/');

Comment: Hello, I can redirect to another page.

Comment: Hello, continuing with this topic. Supose i have a component Login, that post to an api, and if the Login success, i want to redirect to another component (using the this.props.history.push('/Principal) passing the username and password, so in the Principal component uses to retrieve information of this user. How can i pass as an argument the states of the component Login to the component Principal?? . Thanks